# How can I check if a product exists in Magento 2 without throwing \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException?

Tags: magento2, product, exception, repository

I'm attempting to scan an incoming list of products and add any new ones to the catalog.  Therefore, I must run a check on each product to see if it already exists.

I'm using a `ProductRepositoryInterface` via DI to load each product by SKU, but if the product doesn't exist within the catalog (new product), it fails with a `\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException`.

How can I write logic around this so I can either: confirm the product exists, skip it gracefully, and move on **OR** confirm the product doesn't exist, and then add it?  Is there something like an `exists()` method that I'm missing?

```
$product = $this->productRepository->get($xmlProductSku);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here [Magento2 - ProductRepository always throws NoSuchEntityException](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184657/magento2-productrepository-always-throws-nosuchentityexception)

You'd use the concrete Exception class Magento are throwing in the try/catch block

Answer (score 0):

Use this code you can skip the not exsist sku in magento 2 if you are updating anything in products

```
 <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); 
    set_time_limit(0);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    $file = fopen('despUpdate.csv', 'r', '"'); // set path to the CSV file
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface');
    $currentStore = $storeManager->get('en');
    $websiteId = $currentStore->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
    print_r($currentStore->getData());
    // die();
    // used for updating product stock - and it's important that it's inside the while loop
    $stockRegistry = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
    

    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/stockupdate-new.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    $header = fgetcsv($file); // get data headers and skip 1st row

    $required_data_fields = 2;
$counter =0;
    while ( $row = fgetcsv($file, 40000, ",") ) {
        $data_count = count($row);
        if ($data_count < 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        $data = array();
        $data = array_combine($header, $row);
        $sku = $data['sku'];
        // $desp = $data['description'];
        $getShortDescription = $data['short_description'];
        // $setStoreCode=$data['store_view_code'];
        // $setWebsite=$data['product_websites'];
        // $setStore=$data['store_id'];
        if ($data_count < $required_data_fields)
        {
            $logger->info("Skipping product sku " . $sku . ", not all required fields are present to create the product.");
            continue;
        }
        
        // $productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
        // $collection = $productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $data['sku'])->setStore($currentStore)->load();
        // foreach ($collection as $product) 
        // {
                        
                try {
                    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')->get($sku);

                    $productSku=$product->getSku();

                    $product->setData('short_description', $getShortDescription);
                    // $product->setWebsiteIds($websiteId);
                    
                    //update the data the store wise

                    // $product->setData('store_view_code',$setStoreCode);
                    // $product->setData('website_id',$setWebsite);
                    // $product->setData('store_id',$setStore);

                    // for update the information on all store view
                    $product->setStoreId(0);
                    $product->save();
                    // print_r($product->getData());
                    
                    echo "Product Update-".$sku.PHP_EOL;
                } catch (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                    
                    $logger->info('Error importing product sku: '.$sku.'. '.$e->getMessage());
                     // $product = false;
                    continue;
                }     
}
fclose($file);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

What's the problem to catch exception...

```
try {
    $product = $this->productRepository->get($xmlProductSku);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $product = false;
}

if ($product) {
   //some logic
}
```

Comment: You need to catch the concrete exception https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184657/magento2-productrepository-how-to-catch-exception-if-sku-does-not-exist/184665#184665