# Magento2 - ProductRepository how to catch Exception if sku does not exist

Tags: magento2, product, exception

I am writing a console command to update catalog stock, but I am facing some weird issue when trying to load products by sku. I am using this code...

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productRepo = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
```

And then, after getting **$sku** from a csv read function...

```
try {
    $product = $productRepo->get($sku);
} catch (Exception $e){
    $product = false;
}
echo "1"; exit;
```

I have placed that `echo "1";` just to check but that "1" is never reached... result is always **[Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException] Requested product doesn't exist**

So, how can I catch that Exception?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I thought I could catch that using generic php Exception class, but it seems we need to use the concrete throwed Exception

Using this code, then the try/catch block works

```
try {
    $product = $productRepository->get($sku);
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e){
    $product = false;
}
```

Comment: Actually, you can catch the generic class. But the code above will most likely be inside your namespace, which means that you have to catch `\Exception`, not `Exception`.